# Partition problem after HDD to SSD swap

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility, partition

Recently decided to replace my nearly full 500GB HDD with a 1TB SSD to breathe some new life into my mid-2010 Macbook Pro. I used a toaster-style drive cloner (Dyconn Dubbler) to do a sector by sector duplication of the drive. Everything went smoothly but when I booted up from the new drive, I seem to only have around 500 GB of total space, almost all of it full. I fooled around with the partitions a little in disk utility, hoping I could maybe create and delete one, but haven't had any luck. Thought I would be able to drag the partition size but that doesn't seem to be an option. Here is what I see in disk utility with the drive attached/mounted from my other machine:

[image]

Feel like I am missing something obvious here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: forgot to mention, running most recent version of Yosemite

Comment: If you add the output of `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` entered in `Terminal.app` to your question i might improve/modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following `diskutil cs resizeStack` command is vastly undocumented and as such potentially destructive.

***Please backup your Mac OS X before proceeding.***

1. First you have to backup your `Recovery HD`: Start `Terminal.app` and enter
   `defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1` press enter and quit `Terminal.app`
2. Start Disk Utility and enable 'Show every Partition' in the Debug menu
   After a few seconds all partitions should be visible
3. Choose `Recovery HD` on the left side and mount the partition `Recovery HD`. If the `Recovery HD` is missing skip to step 7.

   [image: screen1]
4. Verify the disk

   [image: screen2]
5. Create a disk image of `Recovery HD` and save it read-only externally

   [image: screen3]
6. Check the disk image for restore

   [image: screen4]
7. Detach all external drives
8. Restart into `Internet Recovery Mode` by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
   or a bootable Mavericks or Yosemite Thumb Drive (full system or install).
9. start `Terminal` from the menubar/utilities
10. enter following command at the Terminal prompt:

    > diskutil cs list
11. Copy the Logical Volume (LV) alphanumeric UUID of your CoreStorage volume. The LVUUID should be the fourth listed.
12. Run the following command:

    > diskutil cs resizeStack LVUUID partsize

    According to the number found above it would be:

    > diskutil cs resizeStack xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 100%

    This will hopefully expand your CoreStorage volume to full 1 TB. Depending on your disk this will take several seconds (SSD) or minutes (HDD). After a successful resize check with `diskutil list` if the  `Recovery HD` still exists.
13. Quit `Terminal.app` and start `Disk Utility` and verify the expanded volume.
14. Reboot to Recovery HD and your main drive. Delete the disk image created in step 5 if everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The drive cloner did exactly what it was supposed to do – clone the drive, right down to the original volume's capacity. Try reformatting the SSD with one 1TB partition and then doing a standard Time Machine restore.

Comment: @NeuroBear that might not be necessary. check my answer

Comment: @NeuroBear Please don't accept answers so fast. Check first if it works and then accept it. So please remove it from my answer. Actually i'm answering using an iPhone which isn't very comfortable. Back on a real Mac i'll try to improve it.

Comment: Okay will do--received a similar suggestion elsewhere so it appears like a promising fix but I'll remove it for now.

Comment: @klanomath Wow, you answered with your phone yet you managed to capture and upload the screenshots? How did you do that?

Comment: @ksh ;-) I modified an old answer. But that's also a PITA

Answer (score 0):

If you use CarbonCopyCloner (after reformatting the SSD) it will give the option of moving across the Recovery Partition before moving your 500Gb of data to the new 1Tb partition.